# C# Picture box isnt working

Tags: c#

I have a picture box that can move around and I added a function to add random picture boxes to my form and when the movable picture box intersects with one of the random ones its supposed to start another form but it isn't working. Can anyone help me understand why it is not?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int pb = rand.Next(1, 9);

List<PictureBox> _enemies = new List<PictureBox>();

PictureBox pbRandom = new PictureBox();
int x = rand.Next(1, 1250);
int y = rand.Next(1, 760);
pbRandom.Location = new Point(x, y);

_enemies.Add(pbRandom);

foreach(PictureBox pictureb in _enemies)
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(pictureb); 
    pictureb.Image = Properties.Resources._200w_d;
    if (pictureBox1.Location == pictureb.Location)
    {
        Form bs = new Battle_Screen();
        bs.ShowDialog(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `pictureBox1.Location == pictureb.Location` does not check if the picture boxes intersect. It merely check if they have the same origin. When the have the same size that means that they completely overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if two `PictureBox`es have *exact* same location, not if they intersect each other.

To do that, change line

```
if (pictureBox1.Location == pictureb.Location)
```

with

```
if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureb.Bounds))
```

Comment: @DanielSmith marking this answer as a solution is one way to say thanks :)